# Message box in jQuery

Tags: jquery, msg

Can any one suggest
the code for creating message box in jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean alert(message) ? Or a modal message box ?

Comment: have you tried something on this?

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean just? alert()

```
function hello_world(){ alert("hello world"); }
```

Answer (score 9):

using jQuery UI you can use the dialog that offers. More information at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 5):

jQuery UI Dialog right here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 4):

Try this plugin [JQuery UI Message box](https://github.com/Sergik666/JQuery-UI-Message-Box). He uses jQuery UI Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Let me to recommend you a [jQuery plugin for nice modal alers](http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/jquery.alerts/index.html). It doesn't requires jquery UI.

Demo: http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/jquery.alerts/index.html

Comment: I didn't find a link to Download.

Answer (score 2):

- [Bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) provides modals
- [jQuery UI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [jQuery.msgBox](http://dotctor.github.io/jQuery.msgBox/) provides various kinds of dialogs:
- For 5$ per app it is used, there is http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wont use jquery.ui(that is highly recommended), you can take a look at [Block.UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog) plugin.

Comment: Why  is highly recommended don't to use jquery.u?