# Alert information popup box

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [message box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920459/message-box-in-jquery)

is there any "information popup box" like the alert? 
I would like to have instead of the yellow triangle for exemple a blue exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery UI - Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for a better looking alert style box.

Comment: Yes only this what I find too. It's not the best, but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some plugin, it's not nativ.

I can advise you those :

- http://fancybox.net/
- http://www.99points.info/2010/04/jquery-alert-dialog-boxes-with-demos/
- http://smashingspy.com/32-best-jquery-popup-window-dialog-box-example/